# Unable to run clasp from command-line

Tags: node.js, npm, google-apps-script, clasp

I followed the steps at https://github.com/google/clasp

but it gives me an error :

> -bash: clasp: command not found

My OS is High Sierra 10.13.6,
node version v11.1.0,
npm version 6.4.1.

Comment: I did, with sudo and -g

Comment: yup!  I see this  ├─┬ @google/clasp@1.6.3 and I did re-installed it and still gives me an error

Comment: Was there any error mentioned during installation? like EACESS? https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally Provide more information like logs of installation process.

Comment: This is the message after installation = /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/clasp -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/lib/node_modules/@google/clasp/src/index.js
+ @google/clasp@1.6.3
updated 1 package in 2.851s = I am going to look for the logs. thank you

Comment: What's your binary path? Try checking `export $PATH`. It should be `usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/bin/clasp` If not,  I'm guessing your node installation is done wrongly. You need to reinstall node properly. Check  the above link. Or create a symlink from your actual $PATH to this file `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0/lib/node_modules/@google/clasp/src/index.js`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with my node.js was I installed it using brew.  I resolved the issue by uninstalling node.js in brew and installed it at the terminal.  Now my clasp works.  Thank you.